# Retrieving createDate automatically and saving in database

Tags: grails

My domain class is as follows:

### Person

```
String name
Date createdDate
```

1.) I want createDate to automatically retrieve the **current date and time** and save it in the database. For now, it gives a drop-down to select day month and year and the enduser have to enter it. How can i fix this?

2.) In the drop-down it gives invalid day values. for example an end-user can enter FEB 31st. Which is incorrect. How can i correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, directly from the Grails documentation:

> By default when you have properties called dateCreated and/or
>   lastUpdated in a domain class, Grails automatically maintains their
>   state in the database.

So for example:

```
class Person {
  String name
  Date dateCreated
}
```